# Questions about existential quantifiers in algebra-valued models

Tags: set-theory

Suppose you have the following algebra $4= \{1,\ a,\ b,\ 0\}\ $ such that $0 \leq b \leq a \leq 1$. Now we define the model $V^{A}$ by transfinite recursion. Now consider the following sentence in the language of set theory:

$$\sigma =\exists\, u,v,w,x\ (x \in u \wedge x \notin v \wedge x \notin w \wedge u=v \wedge u=w )$$.

Is it possible that a single name say $\langle x, a\rangle$ is the witness for two existential quantifiers (say $\exists\, v$ and $\exists\, w$) ?

Comment: In principle is possible... Having into the formula the part $u=v \land u=w$, it seems to me that it is necessary that $v=w$.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA ! Well i was trying to show that this sentence receives truth value "b" in the described model . But since the existential quantifier is interpreted as  supremum in the algebra-valued model I guess this is impossible . Am I right ?